# C++ define a class member type according to its template

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

In our code we have the following class:

```
template<class A, class B>
class myClass
{
    typedef std::list<Object<A,B>> MyList;
    typedef std::map<A, typename mList::iterator> MyMap

    MyList mList;
    MyMap mMap;
}
```

class A is metaprogrammed and it can be a string, int and so on.
I would like to change the code so in case class A is a "meta string" a map will be used, otherwise unordered_map will be used.

I've tried to add some more meta programming but haven't succeeded yet:

```
template< class A, class B>
struct MapType // default
{
    typedef std::list<Object<A,B>> MyList;
    typedef std::unordered_map<A,B> MyMap;
}

//TODO struct with templated A (string) to use std::map

template<class A, class B>
class myClass
{
    ???? // if A ~ String define myMap to MAP . otherwise unordered

    MyList mList;
    MyMap mMap;
}
```

any other suggestions for using different map type will be appreciated as well.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly is a "meta string"? A specific class? A class implementing a specific interface? A class with specific properties?

Comment: In the first code block, shouldn't `MyMap` be defined like this `typedef std::map<A, typename MyList::iterator> MyMap`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple solution would be to use `std::conditional` to check if `A` is the same as your "meta string" class (I picked `std::string` for demonstration purposes):

```
template<class A, class B>
class myClass
{
    std::list<Object<A,B>> mList;
    std::conditional_t<std::is_same<A,std::string>::value,
                       std::map<A,B>, std::unordered_map<A,B>> mMap;
};
```

---

Another possibility would be to use partial specialization:

```
template<class A, class B>
class myClass
{
    std::list<Object<A,B>> mList;
    std::unordered_map<A,B> mMap;
};

template<class B>
class myClass<std::string,B>
{
    std::list<Object<std::string,B>> mList;
    std::map<std::string,B> mMap;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Use [std::conditonal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional) trait:

```
template<class A, class B>
class myClass
{
    using MyList = std::list<Object<A,B>>;
    using MyMap = std::conditional_t<IsMetaString<A>::value,
                        std::map<A, typename mList::iterator>,
                        std::unordered_map<A, typename mList::iterator>>;

    MyList mList;
    MyMap mMap;
}
```

Please note I took the liberty to replace your tyedefs with the using type alias, which you should do too.

What is left is to implement `IsMetaString`, which depending on your definition of Meta String could be as simple as:

```
template <class T> struct IsMetaString : std::false_type {};
template <> struct IsMetaString<std::string> : std::true_type {};
```

for instance if by meta string you mean `std::string`. Or you could modify it to your needs.

<sub>Also I think you meant `typename MyList::iterator` instead of `typename mList::iterator`.</sub>

Comment: Since you felt you had to downvote my answer, on the basis its substance was incorporated into another members post, I return the favour.   After all, the content of your post is also essentially in his/hers.   I was distracted in the process of typing my post, so saw neither of yours before posting.

Comment: Bingo.  Generally, however, I aim to only downvote incorrect/invalid answers, not answers that happen to include content that is in other answers.   However, you used your downvote in such a punitive manner, so I have responded in kind.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a "meta string" has type `foo` (a fictitious name I just made up, since you haven't specified what a "meta string" is, you can simply do

```
template< class A, class B>
struct MapType // default
{
    typedef std::list<Object<A,B>> MyList;
    typedef std::unordered_map<A,B> MyMap;

    MyList mList;
    MyMap mMap;
};


template<class B>
struct MapType<foo, B>
{
     typedef std::list<Object<foo, B>> MyList;
     typedef std::map<foo,B> MyMap;

     MyList mList;
     MyMap mMap;
};
```

Comment: sorry, I have to downvote. Your answer is incorporated by `TartanLlama` answer that was posted before you. Me and him have basically the same answer too, but we posted virtually at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

With partial specialization (to be used in pre-C++11 which might not have std::conditional), you do not need to specialize the entire class (which might be a big burden of copying a lot of methods), but you can specialize just the map type:

```
template<class A, class B>
class myClass
{
    template<class X, class ITER_T>
    struct map_type {
        typedef std::map<X, ITER_T> type;
    };

    template<class ITER_T>
    struct map_type<std::string, ITER_T> {
        typedef boost::unordered_map<A /* or std::string */, ITER_T> type;
    };

    typedef std::list<Object<A,B>> MyList;
    typedef map_type<A, typename MyList::iterator>::type MyMap;

    MyList mList;
    MyMap mMap;
};
```

(for pre-C++11 I'd use `boost::unordered_map` instead of `std::unordered_map`)

Comment: Thanks. I will probably use a combination of the methods and perhaps try to avoid the use of conditional thanks to your answer :)

Comment: Sorry, I keep getting declaration of... shadows template parm.
the inner template shadows the outer one. How can I fix this?

Comment: @FPGalero Just change the name of the template parameter for `map_type` :)

Comment: Yes, I didn't try to compile, updated to use different name for the inner template parameter. Also in the specialization I think A can be used or std::string directly (as in the comment).