# Using typedef with a constructor parameter

Tags: c++, typedef, metaclass

Following my previous question, [Defining a class member according to the class template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40356688/c-define-a-class-member-type-according-to-its-template), I've realized that the default bucket count of an `unordered_map` is too low for my purposes.

I have a class template `Base` that will use a map or an unordered map, depending on the template parameters:

```
template<class A, class B> 
class Base {
    template<class T1, class T2>
    struct MapType { typedef boost:unordered_map<...> MType; };
    template<class T2>
    struct MapType<std::string, T2> { typedef std::map<...> MType; };

    typedef typename MapType<...>::MType Map;

    Map mMap;
};
```

I would like to change the default size of `Map` in case it is the latter type by using its consturctor (first parameter defines the size) or by using the unordered map `rehash` function.

My only idea so far is to use the `Base` class constructor to check (`dynamic_cast`?) whether my `mMap` is a map or an unordered map followed by the use of the `rehash` function.

The only limitation is that this code is being used in hundreds of places which mustn't change (can't polymorph my base class).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `MapType` is already a trait class for abstracting *some* aspect of `Map` (its type), you can extend it to abstract another aspect (the construction):

```
template<class A, class B> 
class Base {
    template<class T1, class T2>
    struct MapType {
      typedef boost:unordered_map<...> MType;
      static MType create() { return MType(BUCKET_SIZE); }
    };

    template<class T2>
    struct MapType<std::string, T2> {
      typedef std::map<...> MType;
      static MType create() { return MType(); }
    };

    typedef typename MapType<...>::MType Map;

    Map mMap;

    Base() : mMap(MapType<...>::create()) {}
}
```

Of course, you can pass in some parameters into `create` (and ignore some/all of them in one or the other case), or have the `create`-like function operate on an existing map instead of returning a new one, based on your real use-case needs.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was hoping for!